# Set static height for bar chart using SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bar-chart, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a bar chart and the business has requested that I set the height for each bar at a static height i.e. 40 for the entire result set and then have the data labels displayed above the bar.

How can I set the output to a static height for each bar for the entire chart?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "a static height"?  What is the point of a bar chart if all the bars are at the same height?

Comment: i agree but it's a request from the business.  They want all the bar heights to be the same height and then have the data labels displayed at the top of the bar

Comment: actually after going back and talking to the business they want the bar height to max out at 40 and anything above 40 will remain at 40 with the data label above it with the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like setting the maximum on the Axis plays silly games with the data labels so - as with most things SSRS - lets get creative!

1. Create your chart as normal.
2. Open up your Series Properties and change your Series Data Value Field to `=iif(<Your column value expression here> > 40, 40, <Your column value expression here>)`. This will max out your columns at 40.
3. Open up your Series Label Properties and change the Label Data to `=<Your column value expression here>`.  This will show the true value in your Data Label.

---

## ********************************  Alternatively  *******************************

you could just enable Scale Breaks on your vertical axis and see if the business likes the look of that as, I would imagine from experience, what they *actually* want is more visibility on the difference between the smaller columns that are dwarfed by your `Oct 10` column and not a pointless column chart where comparison is impossible without manually reading a load of figures.